# my NSDateFormatter works only in the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, date

I use a NSDateFormatter which works fine in the simulator, but I get a nil when I run it in the iPhone. I hardcoded the date to be sure of the format, but it fails anyway.

```
NSString *strPubDate = @"Fri, 8 May 2009 08:08:35 GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strPubDate];
```

I tried with different region settings, languages etc. on the iPhone. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code seems to work correctly against the "GMT" tag.

```
NSString *strPubDate = @"Fri, 8 May 2009 08:08:35 GMT";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strPubDate];
```

[RFC822  Date and Time specs](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html#sec-5) use a few "zone" tags and I found the correct symbol to parse the "GMT" tag [Format String for the iPhone NSDateFormatter](http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/)

- z~zzz:   (Specific GMT Timezone Abbreviation)
- zzzz:    (Specific GMT Timezone Name)
- Z:   +0000 (RFC 822 Timezone

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use a specific date format you might want to parse it "by hand" rather than using `NSDateFormatter`. Its behaviour does change depending on the locale, etc. and there are some bugs particularly when you have a timezone in your string.

Having said that, one option in finding what the problem is might be to use the `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` method instead of `dateFromString:`. This way you get an `NSError` object that (in theory) would tell you what the problem is.

BTW, you don't need the `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4` line. iPhone OS only supports the 10.4+ options, though you won't get any errors if you use the "old" style in the Simulator.

Comment: I tried `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` and got an `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "Formatting error."` which is not very meaningful to me. 

SO I am parsing it by hand, it seems to be the more secure way to do it.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

I had also this problem recently (iOS5).
I needed to set also the locale of the `NSDateFormatter` to work on the device.
Without this, `[dateFormatServer dateFromString:dateServer]` was returning null.

```
NSString *dateServer = @"Fri, 8 May 2009 08:08:35 GMT";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatServer = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatServer setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"];

NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
[dateFormatServer setLocale:locale];
[locale release];

NSDate * date = [dateFormatServer dateFromString:dateServer];
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stands out, but to help debug this you could try feeding NSDateFormatter a date object and seeing if the resulting string has any minor differences from the one you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

When I've parsed a date string with "GMT" at the end, I've used the "zzz" format, not "Z".

Answer (score 0):

I second Manuel Spuhler's advice of manually parsing - not my favorite option, but Objective-C's options for that are way too complicated (and lacking in error reporting - anything wrong just spits `nil`, without a hint on the error).

One thing that worked for me is to use C's `strptime` to decouple the date, then reconstruct it as a `NSDate` object. For example, the code below tkes a string received as something like "Monday, 28-Sep-09 18:13:50 UTC" and converts it to a NSDate object adapting the UTC time for the local time:

```
    struct tm time;
    strptime([currentStringValue UTF8String], "%A, %d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S %z", &time);   
    NSDate* myDate = [NSDate dateWithString:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d +0000",
            time.tm_year+1900, time.tm_mon+1, time.tm_mday,
            time.tm_hour, time.tm_min, time.tm_sec]
    ];
```

(could handle other zones by adding other `struct tm` parameters instead of the +0000 fixed time zone, see [time.h entry on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time.h) for details):

Comment: Unfortunately, `dateWithString:` is deprecated on OS X and not supported on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

strptime rescued me aswell.

```
struct tm time;
if (strptime([modDateString UTF8String], "%A, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", &time)) {
            NSString *rDate=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d +0000",
                             time.tm_year+1900, time.tm_mon+1, time.tm_mday,
                             time.tm_hour, time.tm_min, time.tm_sec];
```

This code works with HTTP dates like Thu, 15 Apr 2010 13:53:56 GMT and Fri, 8 May 2009 08:08:35 GMT which was the original question