# Convert time format to relative time Objective C

Tags: objective-c, timezone

How do I convert 2011-05-08T22:08:38Z to a relative time format in Objective C?

Comment: Do you mean 'local time'?  If not, what do you mean by 'relative time'?

Comment: You might care to look at [My NSDateFormatter Works Only in the iPhone Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838893/my-nsdateformatter-works-only-in-the-iphone-simulator).  It isn't a direct duplicate, but it is very close.

Comment: With "relative" I guess you mean an output like *"yesterday"*. See the question [Relative string from NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937230/relative-string-from-nsdate) on how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative string from NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937230/relative-string-from-nsdate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// create a date formatter
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// set the formatter to parse RFC 3339 dates
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
// the formatter parses your date into an NSDate instance
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2011-05-08T22:08:38Z"];

// now to get relative information you can do things like this, which
// will give you the number of seconds since now
NSTimeInterval secondsFromNow = [date timeIntervalSinceNow];

// or this, which will give you the time interval between this data
// and another date
NSTimeInterval secondsFromOther = [date timeIntervalSinceDate:someOtherDateInstance];
```

Comment: sweet. thanks a lot. I was just struggling to get the correct format.