# NSDateFormatter doesn't show time zone abbreviation for "Asia/Kolkata" for the "z" or "zzz" specifier, just the GMT offset

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

On iOS5 simulator and device, NSDateFormatter doesn't show time zone abbreviation for "Asia/Kolkata" for the "z" or "zzz" specifier.

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"z"; // or @"zzz"
dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone;

NSLog(@"date string: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]); // "GMT+05:30", expected "IST"
NSLog(@"time zone abbreviation: %@", [timeZone abbreviationForDate:[NSDate date]]); // "IST"
```

I expect the above code to output:

```
IST
IST
```

but it outputs:

```
GMT+05:30
IST
```

**EDIT**

Setting the locale to an indian locale doesn't seem to help.

```
NSLocale *indianEnglishLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"] autorelease];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:indianEnglishLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"z"]; // or @"zzz"
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSLog(@"date string: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]); // "GMT+05:30", expected "IST"
NSLog(@"time zone abbreviation: %@", [timeZone abbreviationForDate:[NSDate date]]); // "IST"
```

I expect the above code to output:

```
IST
IST
```

but it outputs:

```
GMT+05:30
IST
```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?  [People have mentioned that NSDateFormatter has bugs, especially when a time zone is specified in the format string.  Could this be one of those bugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/838934/9636)

Comment: Do note that in modern iOS the only way recommended by Apple to use a date formatter is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370648/294884

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/310977-nsdateformatter-not-working-on-ios-5.html#311281

> The change in parsing of abbreviated time zone names in iOS 5.0 is a
>   result of an intentional change in the open-source ICU 4.8 library
>   (and the open-source CLDR 2.0 data that it uses), a modified version
>   of which is used to implement some of the NSDateFormatter
>   functionality.
>
> The issue is this: With the *short* timezone formats as specified by z
>   (=zzz) or v (=vvv), there can be a lot of ambiguity. For example, "ET"
>   for Eastern Time" could apply to different time zones in many
>   different regions. To improve formatting and parsing reliability, the
>   short forms are only used in a locale if the "cu" (commonly used) flag
>   is set for the locale. Otherwise, only the long forms are used (for
>   both formatting and parsing).
>
> For the "en" locale (= "en_US"), the cu flag is set for metazones such
>   as Alaska, America_Central, America_Eastern, America_Mountain,
>   America_Pacific, Atlantic, Hawaii_Aleutian, and GMT. It is *not* set
>   for Europe_Central.
>
> However, for the "en_GB" locale, the cu flag *is* set for
>   Europe_Central.
>
> So a formatter set for short timezone style "z" or "zzz" and locale
>   "en" or "en_US" will not parse "CEST" or "CET", but if the locale is
>   instead set to "en_GB" it *will* parse those. The "GMT" style will be
>   parsed by all.
>
> If the formatter is set for the long timezone style "zzzz", and the
>   locale is any of "en", "en_US", or "en_GB", then any of the following
>   will be parsed, because they are unambiguous: "Pacific Daylight Time"
>   "Central European Summer Time" "Central European Time"
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> - Peter Edberg

From http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/313301-nsdateformatter-not-working-on-ios-5.html#313301

> Heath, 
>   Yes, you are correct, for the example you provided above,
>   [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] *should* use the short
>   time zone name "IST". The fact that it does not is due to a deficiency
>   in the "en_IN" locale data in the versions of CLDR data used by ICU in
>   the current OSX and iOS releases (CLDR 1.9.1 and 2.0 respectively).
>   The "en_IN" locale in those CLDR versions did not override or
>   supplement any of the timezone name data from the base "en" locale,
>   whose default content is for "en_US".
>
> This is already fixed for the CLDR 21 release coming in a few days.
>   That is being incorporated into ICU 49 which will be picked up in
>   future OSX and iOS releases.
>
> - Peter E

**---Edit---**

According to the unicode documentation on [formats](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and their [rules](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Time_Zone_Fallback), the `V` format may have been a better choice:

> ...the same format as z, except that metazone timezone abbreviations are to be displayed if available, regardless of the value of [the] commonlyUsed [flag].

In my case, for the following code:

```
NSLocale *indianEnglishLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"] autorelease];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:indianEnglishLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"V"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSLog(@"V date string: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

I receive the following output:

```
V date string: IST
```

Comment: I received - inccu instead of IST for this!

Comment: Same issue as Smitha... print inccu instead of IST

Comment: I tried below dateFormatting string **[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"z"];** and its works perfectly.