# NSDate coming null in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have to get a date from a string. So I am using the below code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//Fri Mar 09 15:31:35 CST 2012
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[newDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"]];
NSLog(@"aDate is %@",[newDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"]);
```

eventDate is coming in the format aDate is **Fri May 18 12:00:37 IST 2012** but date is coming null.

I know it is a small issue but I am really stuck up with it.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the problem appears to be with the timezone portion of the date.  ZZZ expects to be given something like "Fri May 18 12:00:37 -800 2012".

Comment: @PhillipMills Good eye, `ZZZ` specifies `RFC 822`. Lowercase `zzz` is in order for this format I believe.

Comment: Apparently `zzz` depends on something called a "commonlyUsed flag", which I understand not at all.  :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9086117/571506 Let us all be enlightened!

Comment: @PhillipMills I tried converting timezone portion by replacing the timezone with the GMT time and it is working fine.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input string can be parsed with a format of `@"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss VVV yyyy"`.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this before the `dateFromString:` call:

```
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"]];
```

Comment: This code will leak if you are not using ARC, however you can add an `autorelease` in there if you are still working with manual memory management.