# NSDateFormatter:IST not recognised

Tags: nsdateformatter, date-format

IST timezone is not recognised by NSDateFormatter.
Following date is recognised

```
let dateString = "Jun 10, 2015 @ 12.30 AM PDT"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy @ hh-mm-a-zzz"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

but time with IST timezone is not recognised.

```
let dateString = "Jun 10, 2015 @ 12.30 AM IST"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy @ hh-mm-a-zzz"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

Date is nil for IST timezone.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround this helps:

```
let dateString = "Jun 10, 2015 @ 12.30 AM"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyyy @ hh-mm-a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "IST")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

Comment: Date is received from server. timezone can be anything. we can't hardcode

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084980/nsdateformatter-doesnt-show-time-zone-abbreviation-for-asia-kolkata-for-the
the special case is solved by:
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_IN")